# How is this associative array foreach working?

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm perplexed as to how this is not erroring on my server with the highest error reporting to be shown?  Any insight is gladly welcomed.

```
$myArray = ['first' => '1A', 'second' => '2A', 'first' => '2A', 'second' => '2B'];

foreach($myArray as $value) {
    echo $value['first'] . "<br />";
}
```

Outputted:

1A
2A

Comment: Not a major PHP user - but does it really allow the same key used twice in an associative array?  Cause that's whacky

Comment: Can you show how you set the error reporting? Because running this on http://phpfiddle.org/ trigger the erro (Don't hava an account so I can't save the fiddle)

Comment: you can't have duplicate keys. your later `first` and `second` are overwriting the earlier ones. this is not an error. php doesn't care if you overwrite array values. In other words, there is absolutely nothing wrong with this code at the php level. It's a PEBKAC/PICNIC problem.

Comment: And because every `$value` is a string your output will be `2 2`

Comment: @MarcB this code should at least generate illegal string offset warnings in the loop.

Comment: @MarcB There is no overwriting values in the snippet

Comment: not overwriting looks like ignoring

Comment: It's not actually working for me, at least for PHP 5.5.34

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'first' in /Users/.../test.php on line 5
2<br />
Warning: Illegal string offset 'first' in /Users.../test.php on line 5
2<br />%`

Comment: Clearly the problem is that the OP is trying to treat the VALUE of an element of an array, as an array (the value being e.g. 2A, clearly it cannot have a ['first'] attribute). But that's not the question. The question is, why is the error not showing. **We need to see how you're trying to set your error reporting levels.**

Comment: Here's the fiddle that shows the error http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hmd0-88hf (It's on **line 6** `echo $value['first'] . "<br />";`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicated array Keys and this is not allowed on arrays Check [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

You have to reformat Your array to be like this

```
$myArray = [['first' => '1A', 'second' => '2A'], ['first' => '2A', 'second' => '2B']];
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['first']."<br / >";
}
```

Comment: You haven't answered the error supposed to trigger from this line `echo $value['first'] . "<br />";`

Comment: I Edited It Brother, You are welcome, take a look and comment if there are any problems.

Comment: I'll remove my downvote because you're nice :) But take a look at this http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hmd0-88hf run the code, you'll see that the error is not about the duplicate kys, but the `echo $value['first']` line

Comment: Thanks Bro it's my first hour on Stack Flow :) , I see the code and now I understand the main problem of the error, but if he need to get this result `1A & 2A` I give him the right code.

Answer (score 1):

First, You have duplicated the Keys in the array and that is not allowed. 
If you want make the array with the key, you should use something like this:

```
  foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php